# SoftDelete : System.Collections.Generic.List<##.##.Employee>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got in error when I try to perform Sofdelete

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<##.##.Employee>' to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'.

Here is my index I tried to use `ToList()` and `ToList<Employee>`, but it's not working

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var employees = _dbContext.Employees.Where(x => x.status == '1')
           .ToList();
    return employees;
}
```

My `DbContext`:

```cs
public class DataContext : DbContext
{   
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach( var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            var entity = entry.Entity;
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified; 
                entity.GetType().GetProperty("status").SetValue(entity, '0');
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Employee:

```cs
namespace empAPI.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {      
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public char status{ get; set; } = '1';

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Department { get; set; }

        public DateTime?  CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var employees = _dbContext.Employees.Where(x => x.status == '1').ToList();
    return View(employees);
}
```

Read the following article: [Understanding Action Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs#understanding-action-results)

> A controller action returns something called an action result. An
> action result is what a controller action returns in response to a
> browser request.
>
> The ASP.NET MVC framework supports several types of action results
> including:
>
> - ViewResult - Represents HTML and markup.
> - EmptyResult - Represents no result.
> - RedirectResult - Represents a redirection to a new URL.
> - JsonResult - Represents a JavaScript Object Notation result that can be used in an AJAX application.
> - JavaScriptResult - Represents a JavaScript script.
> - ContentResult - Represents a text result.
> - FileContentResult - Represents a downloadable file (with the binary content).
> - FilePathResult - Represents a downloadable file (with a path).
> - FileStreamResult - Represents a downloadable file (with a file stream).
>
> All of these action results inherit from the base ActionResult class.
>
> ***In most cases, a controller action returns a ViewResult.***

Comment: It is also good to note that the user might want to `return PartialView(employees)`, or just json, like `return Ok(employees)`.

Comment: thank you  `return OK(employees)` worked for me @Guilherme

Comment: @kono: I suggest you to change the tag to `asp.net-core-mvc`, because wrong  tag confused me a little. The action results in `asp.net-mvc` and `asp.net-core-mvc` have differences. See [IActionResult Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0)